# Работа со слоями

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем здравствуйте. Нужна ваша помощь. Дали такое задание:
"Квадрат разбит на четыре цветовых сектора относительно осей. При попадании курсора на любой сектор он должен плавно расширяться от центра до определенного размера или до момента снятия курсора мыши с сектора. По нажатию на кнопку он должен возвращаться в исходное состояние."

Нужно написать код с использованием тега div и CSS, но я не совсем понимаю как это реализовать

Вот как это примерно должно выглядеть:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: а вы хотя бы пытались сами сделать? или сразу сюда решили вывалить?

Comment: Пытался конечно. Но к сожалению мне и показывать то нечего

Comment: Можете хотя бы подсказать в каком направлении мне двигаться? Куда смотреть..

Answer (score 2):

Наверное примерно так это делается.

```js
let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
for(let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  boxes[i].addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
    e.target.style.transform = "scale(1.25)";
  });
  boxes[i].addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.target.style.transform = "scale(1)";
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
}

.box {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.orange {
  background-color: #ec7c2f;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}

.green {
  background-color: #6eac45;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.red {
  background-color: #ff0100;
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #599ad5;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box orange"></div>
  <div class="box green"></div>
  <div class="box red"></div>
  <div class="box blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я взял код De.Minov и просто переписал через JS

Comment: Все равно это трансформация на css)) Вероятно, по заданию требуется прямые манипуляции с квадратом, но автор не уточнил

Answer (score 1):

За трансформацию элемента отвечает правило [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), в вашем случае тут подойдёт `transform: scale()`, данное правило назначим для всех цветных элементов при `:hover` (наведении мышью).

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
}

.box {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

.orange {
  background-color: #ec7c2f;
}

.green {
  background-color: #6eac45;
}

.red {
  background-color: #ff0100;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #599ad5;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box orange"></div>
  <div class="box green"></div>
  <div class="box red"></div>
  <div class="box blue"></div>
</div>
```

Чтобы элементы увеличивались "в разные стороны", как это требует задача, можно использовать правило [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin), оно относительно элемента задаёт точку, откуда будет начинаться трансформация элемента, например: оранжевый блок находится в верхнем левом углу, чтобы он увеличивался в ту стороны, нужно указать противоположный угол - нижний правый => `transform-origin: right bottom;` и так дописываем для остальных по аналогии.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
}

.box {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

.orange {
  background-color: #ec7c2f;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}

.green {
  background-color: #6eac45;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.red {
  background-color: #ff0100;
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #599ad5;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box orange"></div>
  <div class="box green"></div>
  <div class="box red"></div>
  <div class="box blue"></div>
</div>
```

---

> По нажатию на кнопку он должен возвращаться в исходное состояние.

Этот момент не понятен, опишите подробнее.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но проблема в том, что сам алгоритм "расширения" должен производится с помощью JavaScript, а не с помощью CSS. То есть квадрат нарисован с помощью css, а алгоритм на JS. При наведении курсора мыши на один из секторов квадрата он начинает плавно увеличиваться. Если я уберу курсор, то сектор просто остается в "расширенном" состоянии, автоматически сектор не уменшается в размерах. В определенный момент сектор все таки достигнет максимума и при наведении курсора перестанет увеличиваться. Чтоб сбросить квадрат к исходному состоянию надо нажать на кнопку.

Comment: Ага, ну направление я вам подсказал, далее всё в ваших руках.

Comment: @Merlin вы же ни слова не сказали в исходном посте про JS, а только про div и CSS, вам на CSS и решили.